# ¿se puede simplificar esta implementacion de modelo en Django?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django, django-models

Este fragmento de codigo pertenece al modelo de mi app en Django y quisiera saber si es posible optimizarlo de la mejor manera, no tengo mucha experiencia y a lo mejor estoy pasando algo por alto. La misma contiene 10 indicadores, cada uno contiene una cantidad variable de criterios pero similar estructura: 1 nombre para el indicador y una serie de criterios los cuales estan compuestos por instancias de la clase "Criterio", cada criterio es diferente. Aqui el fragmento:

```
class Criterio(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=False)
    criterio = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False)
    valor = models.ForeignKey(Valor,on_delete=None)
    relevancia = models.ForeignKey(Relevancia, on_delete=None)
    comentarios = models.CharField(null=True)


class Indicador1(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    vs1 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vs2 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vs3 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vs4 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vs5 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vs6 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vs7 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Indicador2(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    su1 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    su2 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    su3 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    su4 = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

... # Y asi hasta 10 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el detalle esta en la relacion de la base de datos,deberias agregar detalles del tipo de relacion que deseas que tenga(1:1, 1:M, M:M), segun entiendo quieres tener varios indicadores, los cuales tengan varios criterios.Podria haber varias formas de hacerlo, prueba lo siguiente:

```
class Criterio(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=False)
    criterio = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False)
    valor = models.ForeignKey(Valor,on_delete=None)
    relevancia = models.ForeignKey(Relevancia, on_delete=None)
    comentarios = models.CharField(null=True)


class Indicador(models.Model):
    nombre = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
    
class CriterioIndicador(models.Model):
    criterio = models.ForeignKey('Criterio', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    indicador = models.ForeignKey('Indicador', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Esta es una forma de verlo, igual puedes agregar mas informacion en caso que no sea lo que buscabas.
Tambien puedes revisar este tema en la documentacion oficial de Django [Django Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#relationships)